# Visual Hit Test using a geometry as a parameter

Tags: wpf

When you use a geometry as a hit test parameter, if there are multiple shapes contained within the geometry how do you get all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Scan [the article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx) and please notice that VisualTreeHelper.HitTest has 3 overloads. One of them has "filterCallback" and a "resultCallback". With those two you can control what is investigated and what is "returned".

If you dont feel like reading whole, at least check sections:
- *"Using a Hit Test Result Callback"*
- *"Using a Hit Test Filter Callback"*

Please mind that "returned" means "passed to the resultCallback". In that callback you MUST store each visited partial result (if it is interesting/relevant to you) in some place of your choice.
If you dont - you will not have any actual results.
If you do - you will have your results exactly there where you stored them.